# Pandas query using list and return only rows where all list element are found

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to setup a pd.query() based expression for extracting all rows with values that are shared between X number of list elements.

An example .csv file can be found here. I load it locally on my own machine.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nKCFUFUDm-ukwRyoTfnvfBeAq9KpW-NZ/view?usp=sharing

My goal is to find all "Short_name" (=protein domains) which are found in all of the different "Query".

Attempted workflow:

1. Extract a list/dataframe of all "Query" entries without duplicates
2. Use the list to query the original "data2" dataframe where a "Short_name" is found in all of the list elements.
3. It would also be nice to find "Short_name" that are found in X out of Y list elements.

```
data = pd.read_csv(r".csv)
data2 = data.query('Hit_type == "non-specific"')
data2.reset_index(inplace=True)
query = data2.drop_duplicates(subset='Query')
query_list = query["Query"].squeeze()
list_extract = query["Query"].tolist()
#This gives a list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
#list_extract

# I now want to query the dataframe for all "Short_name" found in all list_extract elements.

data2.query('Query == @list_extract and ....', inplace=True)
data2
```

What is a good solution to the above problems? Am I in need of a function or some built-in method like isin() ? Thanks.

Comment: You can select rows of a DataFrame (`data2`) where `columnname` is any element in `list_extract` using `data2.query('columnname in @list_extract')`

Comment: Can you fix your code not to have this non-terminating string?

Comment: Shared file can not be accessed.

Comment: Sorry about the link, should be fixed now!